# Display different css or Information based on previous page

Tags: css, previous

I've run into a bit of a tricky problem that I'm probably over thinking. I need to be able to display different css depending on what campaign page the user has come from.

To better illustrate:

```
Campaign 1 \
Campaign 2 ----> Information or css  ----> page
Campaign 3 /
```

I hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function called `wp_get_referer()` that you could use to do this. [Codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

```
$page_referrer = wp_get_referer();
if ( $page_referrer == 'campaign-1-url') {
    // Campaign 1 css
}
```

You'll have to craft the conditional statement to fit yours needs.